Instead of setting maxSupportedTransactionVersion as 0 why am I getting this error?
I'm trying to verify a Solana transaction using the QuickNode RPC endpoint, but I'm getting the following error:
Starting verification process...  
Amount: 0.001  
Error during transaction verification: SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get transaction: Transaction version (0) is not supported by the requesting client. Please try the request again with the following configuration parameter: "maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0  
at Connection.getParsedTransaction (D:\Project1-proto\backend\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7456:13)  
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)  
at async verifyDepositTransaction (file:///D:/Project1-proto/backend/utils/transaction.utils.js:19:25)  
at async depositWithPhantom (file:///D:/Project1-proto/backend/controllers/transactions.controller.js:16:21)  

Here is the code I’m using for verification:
export async function verifyDepositTransaction(pubkey, amount, signature) {
  console.log('Starting verification process...');
  console.log('Public Key:', pubkey);
  console.log('Amount:', amount);
  console.log('Signature:', signature);

  const connection = new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_RPC_ENDPOINT, {
    maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
    commitment: 'confirmed'
  });

  try {
    const transaction = await connection.getParsedTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');
    console.log('Fetched Transaction:', JSON.stringify(transaction, null, 2));

    if (!transaction || !transaction.transaction || !transaction.transaction.message) {
      console.error('Transaction not found or invalid format.');
      return false;
    }

    const fromPubkey = new PublicKey(pubkey);
    const toPubkey = new PublicKey(process.env.COMPANY_SOL_ADDRESS); // Replace with your company wallet address  
    const lamports = parseFloat(amount) * 1e9; // Convert SOL to lamports  

    console.log('From Public Key:', fromPubkey.toString());
    console.log('To Public Key:', toPubkey.toString());
    console.log('Lamports:', lamports);

    const instructions = transaction.transaction.message.instructions;

    // Ensure instructions array exists and is not empty  
    if (!instructions || instructions.length === 0) {
      console.error('No instructions found in the transaction.');
      return false;
    }

    console.log('Instructions found:', instructions.length);

    // Iterate through the instructions to find a match  
    const isValid = instructions.some((instruction, index) => {
      console.log(`Checking instruction ${index + 1} of ${instructions.length}`);
      console.log('Instruction:', JSON.stringify(instruction, null, 2));

      if (!instruction || !instruction.programId || !instruction.parsed) {
        console.error('Instruction is missing required fields.');
        return false;
      }

      const parsedInfo = instruction.parsed.info;

      // Check that the program ID is SystemProgram, and the sender and receiver addresses match  
      const matches = instruction.programId.equals(SystemProgram.programId) &&
        parsedInfo.source === fromPubkey.toString() &&
        parsedInfo.destination === toPubkey.toString() &&
        parsedInfo.lamports === lamports;

      console.log('Instruction match result:', matches);
      return matches;
    });

    console.log('Transaction validation result:', isValid);
    return isValid;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during transaction verification:', error);
    return false;
  }
}

I am getting this error which is really irritating. I've asked every AI tool about it and got no solution. The RPC endpoint I am using is of Quiknode. My Solana library is up to date so that's not the root of the error.

Possible dupe: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/getconfirmedtransaction-return-error-transaction-version-0-is-not-supported-by
